# Excel VBA: Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class

Tags: excel, vba, match

I'm trying to do a match search between two workbooks to see if a name entered in Wbook1 is in column A of Wbook2.  For example... I have "name1" in cell D4 of workbook1... I then want the macro to search column A of workbook2 to find where "name1" is.  I'm not worried about the name not existing on workbook2 as it should always be there.

Using Excel 2007, code is:

```
Sub ViewData()
    Dim xlo As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlw As New Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlz As String
    Dim result As Double
    Dim SalesExec As String
    SalesExec = Range("d4").Value 'D4 contains the name from workbook1 I want to search for
    xlz = Range("y1").value  'This cell contains the file path for workbook 2
    Set xlw = xlo.Workbooks.Open(xlz) 'Path is correct as the desired workbook does open
    result = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(SalesExec, xlo.Worksheets("Data").Range("A:A"), 0) 'Data is the sheet in workbook2 containing the list of names
    Range("Q14").value = result
    xlw.Save
    xlw.Close
    Set xlo = Nothing
    Set xlw = Nothing
End Sub
```

If I remove .WorksheetFunction, I get an 'object or application defined error'.  As the code stands, I get the 'unable to get the match property of the worksheetfunction class' error and I'm not sure why.

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Why VBA and not excel formula? Also why not `Vlookup`?

Comment: Using VBA because there are security validation rules that I'll eventually take into account via VBA.  Using Match instead of Vlookup because I'll be returning the entire row where the name is located.

The validation rules will exist because multiple people will be using the macro to look up employee information.

Comment: I also forgot to mention that workbook2 will be in a shared drive, and I can't use an excel formula to run the match unless the workbook is open.  I want this workbook to open without being viewed and need VBA to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. I have commented the code so you will not face a problem understanding it.

```
Sub ViewData()
    Dim xlo As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlw As New Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlz As String
    Dim result As Double
    Dim LRow As Long
    Dim SalesExec As String

    SalesExec = Range("d4").Value

    xlz = Range("y1").Value

    Set xlw = xlo.Workbooks.Open(xlz)

    With xlw.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        '~~> Find the last row cause Range("A:A") in match will give error
        LRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    xlo.Visible = True

    '~~> Result is double so ensure that whatever you are trying to find is as Double
    '~~> Also It should be xlw.Worksheets("Data") and not xlo.Worksheets("Data")
    result = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(SalesExec, xlw.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1:A" & LRow), 0)

    Range("Q14").Value = result
    xlw.Save
    xlw.Close
    Set xlo = Nothing
    Set xlw = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent.  This works.  Perhaps the error was related to not finding the last row?  Either way, thanks!